# Bash script change the directory using for loop

Tags: bash

I have below directory structure I'm trying to navigate to each directory and need to perform some activity, let say when the activity is done need to return home/user path

```
pwd
/home/user
cd /home/user/inbound/app1
cp -r app1.txt /home/user/backup/inbound/app1

pwd
/home/user
cd /home/user/inbound/app2
cp -r app2.txt /home/user/backup/inbound/app2
```

```
┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-1OOLTMI)-[/home/user]
└─# tree
.
├── inbound
│   ├── app1
│   │   └── app1.txt
│   └── app2
│       └── app2.txt
└── outbound
    └── app3
        └── app3.txt

6 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: "let say when the activity is done need to return home/user path" => `cd /home/user`?

Comment: Please elaborate if you need to return to the old pwd or need help for performing the activity

Comment: You don't need to change the current directory to copy a file. `cp -r /home/user/inbound/app1/app1.txt /home/user/backup/inbound/app1` works. Note that the `-r` option of `cp` is useless to copy files.

Comment: Or, if you do traverse each directory, simply exiting the script will return you to the directory you started in (cardinal rule of environment - "A child can never modify the environment of its parent") When you run a script, it runs in a subshell (child-process)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - thanks for the input, now the main concern usng loop i need to copy the files from each directory and move into destination path.

Comment: There are several alternatives you may not be aware of (1) pushd destdir, do_your_cmds, popd (temporary change directory and back). (2) cd destdir, do_your_cmds, cd -, (3) tar -C srcdir -cf - file1 file2 file3 | tar -C destdir -xf -